# Trigger OSX runloop from Qt

Tags: macos, qt, diskarbitration

I'm writing an application in C++ using Qt on Mac. I want to detect drives being mounted and unmounted so I am using the DiskArbitration framework. I registered some callback functions via `DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback` and `DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback` but these only fire when there is a runloop.

What is the best way to start a suitable runloop ?

QThread with `CFRunLoopRun` (sounds a bit excessive) ?

Please give details, I am not well versed in threads.

Comment: Is it even possible to do `CFRunLoopRun` from `QThread`? I want to use it for some library that does not have a specialized method like `DASessionSetDispatchQueue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X 10.7+ you can use `DASessionSetDispatchQueue` to have your callbacks invoked on a dispatch queue of your choosing. You could then forward the data from the callback over to your regular Qt event loop.